# When implementing infinite scroll (paginating results in UITableView when scrolling to bottom): reloadData or insertRows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When implementing infinite scroll in a `UITableView` (loading additional results to the data source when the user scrolls to bottom), should the table be updated by `reloadData()` or by inserting rows (perhaps through a batch update)?

I'm using `reloadData()` right now and it works just fine but I'm not sure what's happening behind the scenes and how efficient this is. With `reloadData()`, the new rows are inserted at the bottom of the table and the table doesn't jump (so to the user it's a seamless update), but is UIKit reloading the entire table unnecessarily (and we just don't see it)? Because new rows are only added to the table when the user is scrolled to the bottom, this could mean that there are a large number of cells above it and out of view. I know those cells aren't in the view hierarchy anyway (because the table adds and removes cells as the user scrolls), but does `reloadData()` efficiently update pagination blocks regardless of this mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are actually very few cells on screen at anytime, reloadData isn't really noticeable slower than insert.  The real difference is in the animation.  reload just adds the new cells with no animation where as insert will allow you to animate the cells in.  The newer way (iOS 13+) to do this is to not call either method but instead use [UITableViewdiffableDatasource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource) and it will perform the update automatically with the animation you specify (this is much more similar to how RxCocoa and IGListKitWork).